# Tortoise SVN not showing the ! exclamation

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am not sure why but sometimes my SVN project seems like it is not synced to SVN: the exclamations (!) on the folders go away and now i can't tell which folders I have made changes to.

I can still commit my files, but it makes it difficult to keep up with the changes I have made on the files. The files seem like they aren't even added to the project as if I copied/pasted them in there but haven't added/committed them yet.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Couple of ideas in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217880/windows-explorer-icons-in-tortoisesvn-take-a-long-time-to-refresh-to-correct-sta

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have that problem all the time. I don't think there is a solution for it. Sometimes if I refresh the folder it updates it to green check mark but this is something tortoise needs to work on. I definitely feel your pain.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my computer, the icons showed up again..originally i restarted and it did not work, but after a while i restarted again and this time the icons came back.