# svn shows no changes but windows shows the changed icon next to folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I update my repo folder, it shows as updated with a green checkmark. But within a few seconds, the checkmark changes to a red X, as if files have changed...

When I right click "Check for modifications" nothing shows up...

How can I find out what has changed?

When I follow the folder paths through the folders with red X's, I end up at a folder with files that do not have red X's.

Comment: The Windows explorer often takes some time to refresh the icons. I wouldn´t rely on them. Did you try to refresh manually (F5)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Explorer icons in TortoiseSVN take a long time to refresh to correct state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217880/windows-explorer-icons-in-tortoisesvn-take-a-long-time-to-refresh-to-correct-sta)

Comment: @Yeti This is not a duplicate.  I'm having the same problem with TortoiseSVN.  It worked fine for months, and then a couple weeks ago this problem started happening.